# hslogger disable output to console

Tags: haskell, logging, hslogger

The following is supposed to configure hslogger for a Happstack application:

```
main = do
  accessLogHandler <- fileHandler "access" INFO
  updateGlobalLogger "Happstack.Server.AccessLog.Combined" (setLevel INFO)
  updateGlobalLogger "Happstack.Server.AccessLog.Combined" (setHandlers [accessLogHandler])
  simpleHTTP nullConf app
```

Access logs are going both to my "access" file and to stderr.  According to [this page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hslogger-1.2.10/docs/System-Log-Logger.html), `setHandlers` is supposed to "Set the Logger's list of handlers to the list supplied. All existing handlers are removed first."  I had assumed that console output would be an "existing handler", but apparently it is not.

How do you deactivate hslogger's console output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I spent about an hour and a half to figure this out. Code of `hslogger` is not very clean and doesn't make it easy to understand it.

**EXPLANATION**

Printing in terminal happens because there exist `rootLogger` with `rootLoggerName = ""` and `stderr` handler. When you print something to specific logger you also print to all parents of this exact logger. It happens so that `rootLoggerName` is one of parents for `Happstack.Server.AccessLog.Combined`.

**SOLUTION**

The way I found to disable terminal logging is just to set all handler of root logger name to empty list, like this:

```
updateGlobalLogger rootLoggerName (setHandlers [])
```

Unfortunately, this exact code won't compile because type of `[]` is too ambiguous for `setHandlers`. You can solve this type inference issue with `-XTypeApplications` extension. Here is the full code example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import GHC.IO.Handle (Handle)
import System.Log.Logger
import System.Log.Handler.Simple

main :: IO ()
main = do
  accessLogHandler <- fileHandler "access" INFO
  let name = "Happstack.Server.AccessLog.Combined"
  updateGlobalLogger name (setHandlers [accessLogHandler])
  updateGlobalLogger name (setLevel INFO)
  updateGlobalLogger rootLoggerName (setHandlers @(GenericHandler Handle) [])
  infoM name "Hello!"
```

This `infoM` will print only to file and won't print to terminal.

Comment: Luckily, calling `setHandlers` and using `TypeApplications` should not even be necessary.  The section about `removeLogger` on [this page](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hslogger-1.2.10/docs/System-Log-Logger.html#g:9) says "The root logger's default handler that writes every message to stderr can be removed by using this function before any handlers have been added to the root logger:" `updateGlobalLogger rootLoggerName removeHandler`.  So apparently, the stderr logger is the only handler belonging to the root logger, and there is going to be some stability to that statement.